# Google Charts Flip

Tags: javascript, web, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a timeline chart using Google Charts, something similar to this image[image]

The thing is I need the chart to be drawn from right to left such that the y-axis becomes on the right side and the labeling of the x-axis is reversed. Any ideas? I have searched the API documentation but could not find anything useful. Is there any any other library that can do it ?

Comment: Unfortunately although lineChart supports this, the customization options for timeLine are really few, and there is no way as far as I know to archieve this. You might need to look for other libraries

Comment: The timeline takes either a number or a date as third and fourth parameters, so you can recode the numbers (x=max-x) so that you get the reversed x effect. Have you made any progress? I am trying to flip coordinates.. y-x...